# Jquery .click does not work in combination with PrettyPhoto

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

[PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) gallery script.

I want to load only first 3 photos of each gallery. If user starts viewing these first photos, the script must load all photos of that gallery.

```
<a href="photo_1.jpg" data-bid="6780" data-rel="PrettyPhoto[g1a][1]"><img src="thumbnail_1.jpg" />
<a href="photo_2.jpg" data-bid="6781" data-rel="PrettyPhoto[g1a][1]"><img src="thumbnail_2.jpg" />
<a class="loadimgs" data-gallery="1" href="photo_3.jpg" data-bid="6782" data-rel="PrettyPhoto[g1a][1]"><img src="thumbnail_3.jpg" />
```

As you can see above, the link of **photo_3.jpg** contains **class="loadimgs"**. When user clicks on the 3rd thumbnail, the PrettyPhoto must show the full image and Jquery at the same time must send a request to **more-images.php** to load all links/thumbnails of this gallery to the container **.load_more_images**

```
<div style="display:none" class="load_more_images" id="1"></div>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Does not work means that

```
$(document).on('click',".loadimgs", function()
```

is totally ignored.
When I click on the 3rd thumbnail, PrettyPhoto, opens a full size photo but there is no request to **more-images.php** file. Browser console does not show any errors, nothing.

Is it possible that .click does not work in combination with PrettyPhoto? If so, can you suggest any other way how to call the **more-images.php** file when user clicks on 3rd thumbnail?

```
$("a[data-rel^='PrettyPhoto[g1a]']").PrettyPhoto({
allow_resize:0,
deeplinking:false
});

$(document).on('click',".loadimgs", function(){
var gallery_id=$(this).attr("data-gallery");
$('.load_more_images').load("/more-images.php?gallery_id="+gallery_id");
alert("It works");
});
```

Comment: please can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the way you attach the event with this:

```
$('.loadimgs').click(function(ev){
    var gallery_id=$(this).attr("data-gallery");
    $('.load_more_images').load("/more-images.php?gallery_id="+gallery_id);
    alert("It works" + gallery_id);
});
```

You also have a quote that cause a fail at the end of this, before the last parentheses: $('.load_more_images').load("/more-images.php?gallery_id="+gallery_id");

Comment: Oh, and you also need to close the a tags if they are not closed (in the code attached they are not) and also replace the .PrettyPhoto with .prettyPhoto.

Comment: Thank you! This solve the described problem but creates a new problem. PrettyPhoto is ignoring the newly loaded images and don't display them. Need some way how to push the loaded images to the 3 first images. Have to submit a new question.